# How can I filter Django models using field lookups that span relationships and aggregation functions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a set of four models representing rental properties.

The **Property** model stores the property's name and who created it.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

A **Property** can have many **Area** instances throug a *ForeignKey* relationship. An **Area** has an **AreaType** through a *ForeignKey* relationship as well, and many **Amenities** through a *ManyToManyField*.

```
class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AreaType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amenities = models.ManyToManyField(Amenity, null=True, blank=True)

class AreaType(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Amenity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am familiar with field lookups that do and do not span relationships, as well as filtering through kwargs.

What I am not familiar with is combining field lookups and aggregation functions.
**And therefore, given the models above, I would like to:**

1. Retrieve all Properties that have at least 3 Amenities with the name 'Television'.
2. Retrieve all Properties that have at least 2 Areas with an AreaType name of 'Bathroom'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all properties with ammenities with name Television:

###### Big thanks to @Waldemar Podsiadło, I misunderstood the question. He provided the correct answer for counting tv's.

```
Property.objects.filter(area_set__amenities__name="Television")\
    .annotate(tv_count=models.Count('area_set__amenities')\
    .filter(tv_count__gte=3))
```

Should retrieve all properties relating to ammenities with name Television, and with a count greater than or equal to 3.

You did not define a `related_name`, so therefore the reverse of area will be `area_set`.
From there on, you have the properties available to you as fields, so you can just continue to filter from that.

To access a field in the query, separate it with double underscores `__`, this also works with expressions, like `__count`, and `__sum` (most of the time).

You can figure out what query expressions you can use with:

```
Property._meta.fields.get_field('your_field_name').get_lookups()
```

A link to the [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/) to learn more about querysets, and filtering.

A link to the [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/) to learn more about filtering.

##### Edit: Kwargs example:

```
def filter_my_queryset(tv_count: dict, *args, **kwargs):
    Property.objects.filter(**kwargs)\
        .annotate(tv_count=models.Count(*args)\
        .filter(**tv_count)) # Need a second dict, unless you always need a gte filter. Then you can dynamically do it.
```

Or, you could dynamically get the amenities, by comparing the last part of the expression with the fields on a model; if its not a field, cut it out. In this example that should cut out `area_set__amenities__name` to `area_set__amenities`

You can get a list of fields from the model with:

```
field_name_list = []
for i in mymodel._meta.fields:
    field_name_list.append(i.name)
```

Or alternatively; use `hasattr()` to check if a field exists. This might give false positives though, since any attributes count toward it.

> Sidenote:
>
> Read this doc, I think you'll find it very useful if you need to pack a lot of queries into functions. Custom QuerySets are great!
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Thank you, Nigel. Bonus question: is there a way to do this exclusively using lookups via kwargs?

Answer (score 3):

@nigel239 I think you don't need to use _set in filtering reverse relationship, you just use model name. In addition you can make more with Django ORM. For first question it goes like:

```
Property.objects.filter(area__amenities__name="Television")
        .annotate(tv_ocurance=Count('area__amenities', filter=Q(area__amenities__name="Television")))
        .filter(tv_ocurance__gte=3)
```

you can do exactly the same for second query.

UPDATE:

As @nigel239 suggested it can be done like:

```
Property.objects.filter(area__amenities__name="Television")\
        .annotate(tv_count=Count('area__amenities')\
        .filter(tv_count__gte=3)
```

Or my way:

```
 Property.objects\
        .annotate(tv_ocurance=Count('area__amenities', filter=Q(area__amenities__name="Television")))\
        .filter(tv_ocurance__gte=3)
```

Comment: Whoops, thanks, I misunderstood the question. You don't need to specify the filter in the Count expression, we have already filtered.

Comment: @nigiel239, yes the first filter do the job. I even tested it. I update my answer to show result